# How to check for ANY missing values

Tags: stata

I know a way of  finding and identifying missing values for a **particular** variable.

For the variable `avedmajor`, I could do

```
tab avedmajor, m
```

Then,

```
gen avedmajormissing=0

replace avedmajormissing=1 if avedmajor==.
```

But how to see if my dataset has missing values in any of the variables without going through each one of them?

Thanks.

Comment: Your second example would be better as `gen avedmajormissing = missing(avedmajor)`. Note also that your syntax does nothing about extended missing values and is only for numeric variables.

Comment: I assume your code includes both numeric and string values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One command is:

```
misstable summarize
```

But see also:

```
help missing##useful
```

and more generally:

```
help missing
```

Comment: I assume when it says "variables nonmissing or string", it means that I don't have missing values at all?

Comment: As I understand it, `misstable` will not count string missings, even with the `all` option.

Answer (score 4):

I'd add `mdesc` command to proposed solutions. According to [description](http://ideas.repec.org/c/boc/bocode/s457318.html) `mdesc`:

> Produces a table with the number of missing values, total number of
>   cases, and percent missing for each variable in varlist. mdesc works
>   with both numeric and character variables.

So advantage to `misstable` solution is that it works with both numeric and string variables in one go.

```
sysuse auto
mdesc
```

Gives a nice overview of missings:

```
    Variable    |     Missing          Total     Percent Missing
----------------+-----------------------------------------------
           make |           0             74           0.00
          price |           0             74           0.00
            mpg |           0             74           0.00
          rep78 |           5             74           6.76
       headroom |           0             74           0.00
          trunk |           0             74           0.00
         weight |           0             74           0.00
         length |           0             74           0.00
           turn |           0             74           0.00
   displacement |           0             74           0.00
     gear_ratio |           0             74           0.00
        foreign |           0             74           0.00
----------------+-----------------------------------------------
```

Comment: If interested, install by `ssc inst mdesc` in Stata, not via your browser.

Comment: Much better... does strings and numeric in a super clean format, recommend!

Answer (score 1):

`missings` from the *Stata Journal* offers a bundle of subcommands.

`search dm0085` will yield a clickable link to the latest version of the file.

The write-up in [the *Stata Journal*](https://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=dm0085) will emerge from behind a paywall on the publication of *Stata Journal* 18(4) in December 2018 or January 2019.

Before then, or even after, the examples [in the Statalist announcement](https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1308777-missings-now-available-from-ssc-new-program-for-managing-missings) give much flavour.

Here is a token:

```
. webuse nlswork, clear 
(National Longitudinal Survey.  Young Women 14-26 years of age in 1968)

. missings report

Checking missings in all variables:
15082 observations with missing values

age           24
msp           16
nev_mar       16
grade          2
not_smsa       8
c_city         8
south          8
ind_code     341
occ_code     121
union       9296
wks_ue      5704
tenure       433
hours         67
wks_work     703

. missings report, min(1000)

Checking missings in all variables:
15082 observations with missing values

union     9296
wks_ue    5704
```

This command is considered to supersede `nmissing`.

ORIGINAL POST BELOW July 9 2014

Various commands help. See e.g. `codebook`. For one user-written command, install `nmissing`.

```
. search nmissing, historical

Search of official help files, FAQs, Examples, SJs, and STBs

FAQ     . . . . . .  Can I quickly see how many missing values a variable has?
    . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  UCLA Academic Technology Services
    7/08    http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/stata/faq/nmissing.htm

Example . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . Useful non-UCLA Stata programs
    . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  UCLA Academic Technology Services
    7/08    http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/ado/world/

SJ-5-4  dm67_3  . . . . . . . . . .  Software update for nmissing and npresent
    (help nmissing if installed)  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  N. J. Cox
    Q4/05   SJ 5(4):607
    now produces saved results

SJ-3-4  sg67_2  . . . . . . . . . .  Software update for nmissing and npresent
    (help nmissing, npresent if installed)  . . . . . . . . . .  N. J. Cox
    Q4/03   SJ 3(4):449
    updated to include support for by, options for checking
    string values that contain spaces or periods, documentation
    of extended missing values .a to .z, and improved output

STB-60  dm67.1  . . . .  Enhancements to numbers of missing and present values
    (help nmissing if installed)  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  N. J. Cox
    3/01    pp.2--3; STB Reprints Vol 10, pp.7--9
    updated with option for reporting on observations

STB-49  dm67  . . . . . . . . . . . . .  Numbers of missing and present values
    (help nmissing if installed)  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  N. J. Cox
    5/99    pp.7--8; STB Reprints Vol 9, pp.26--27
    commands to list the numbers of missing values and nonmissing
    values in each variable in varlist
```

Here is an example:

```
. webuse nlswork
(National Longitudinal Survey.  Young Women 14-26 years of age in 1968)

. nmissing

age                                 24
msp                                 16
nev_mar                             16
grade                                2
not_smsa                             8
c_city                               8
south                                8
ind_code                           341
occ_code                           121
union                             9296
wks_ue                            5704
tenure                             433
hours                               67
wks_work                           703
```

Comment: I installed it and ran it but nothing at all showed up.

Comment: That could mean no missing values. Try `sysuse auto` followed by `nmissing`. You should see a report for `rep78`.

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be `misschk` from the *SPost* site. Type `findit misschk` to install it. Here's an example:

```
sysuse auto,clear
replace price=. if (_n==1|_n==3)  // additional missing values
misschk
```

Without specifying the `varlist`, `misschk` just checks all variables.

The standard output gives you the number as well as percentage of missing values on each variable.

```
Variables examined for missing values

   #  Variable        # Missing   % Missing
--------------------------------------------
   1  price                 2         2.7
   2  mpg                   0         0.0
   3  rep78                 5         6.8
   4  headroom              0         0.0
   5  trunk                 0         0.0
   6  weight                0         0.0
   7  length                0         0.0
   8  turn                  0         0.0
   9  displacement          0         0.0
   10 gear_ratio            0         0.0
   11 foreign               0         0.0
```

It also counts all the different missing patterns.

```
   Missing for |
         which |
    variables? |      Freq.     Percent        Cum.
---------------+-----------------------------------
 1_3__ _____ _ |          1        1.35        1.35
 1____ _____ _ |          1        1.35        2.70
 __3__ _____ _ |          4        5.41        8.11
 _____ _____ _ |         68       91.89      100.00
---------------+-----------------------------------
         Total |         74      100.00
```

Lastly, it summarizes the amount of missing values by cases.

```
Missing for |
   how many |
 variables? |      Freq.     Percent        Cum.
------------+-----------------------------------
          0 |         68       91.89       91.89
          1 |          5        6.76       98.65
          2 |          1        1.35      100.00
------------+-----------------------------------
      Total |         74      100.00
```

`misschk` also has a couple of other neat features with additional options you can find out about with `help misschk`.